# HTTPS=true is not working

Tags: environment-variables

I'm trying to set the environment variable `HTTPS=true` in macOS bash shell but it doesn't work when I `printenv` the variable `HTTPS=true` doesn't appear:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/kr/848p_nc116l4vvkbgkc_c1200000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.PkTkQaYUUc/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=421.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=44933CE9-8A15-40AD-A534-286602490A93
USER=rh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.6RrPiiuDzY/Listeners
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/gerardo
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/rh
LOGNAME=rh
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a8
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

to set the env variable I used the commands `set HTTPS=true` and `HTTPS=true`

I have 3 questions:

1. What's happening?
2. How can I fix it?
3. Which file I have to use in macOS to set the env variable as a permanent variable

Comment: I'm using bash shell

Comment: See the proposed duplicate question. The file you're after is (most likely) `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Christopher Or just `printenv HTTPS` (will get the value).

Comment: `printenv HTTPS` produces no result but set | grep HTTPS works!

Comment: You're setting a shell variable and not an *environment* variable...

Comment: @ger That was in reply to a now deleted comment in which Christopher used `export HTTPS=true`.  This creates an environment variable. He then did `printenv | grep HTTPS` and I suggested using `printenv HTTPS` instead.

Comment: when I export HTTPS it works